# Saving a matrix but loading a struct in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, file, matrix, struct, io

I am currently working on a project which creates and requires more data than my RAM can handle. Therefore, I am saving my data as .mat files for processing. However, when I try to save my **3 dimensional** `uint8` matrix as a file and load it up again (using the `save` and `load` functions), I do not get the same data as before. Calling `whos` in fact, seems to load a *1*-by-*1* struct. I have been crawling through the `save` and `load` MATLAB documentation, but cannot seem to understand how I can achieve what I want to do.

I am currently working on the **R2014b** MATLAB with an **8GB RAM**. The exact `whos` output to the variable I am trying to save and load is given below:

[image: whos output]

Am I supposed to be adding an option to the `save` and `load` functions? I understand that there is an option to specify the precision of the numbers being stored but not their data type and structure. My calls for the functions are below:

**Where I save my File**

```
for i = 1:N 
    for j = times(i,1):times(i,2)
        frame = vreader.read(j); 
        temp_bead(j,1:mod_height,:) = frame(1:mod_height,:); 
        dispstat(sprintf('Processing Bead %d/%d',i,N),'timestamp');
    end
    % Copying the matrix data into a new matrix 
    matrixname = strcat('UncroppedBeadMatrix',int2str(i));
    dir = strcat(pwd,foldername,'\',matrixname); 
    whos('temp_bead');
    save(dir, 'temp_bead','-double');
end
```

**Where I load my file**

```
foldername = '\UncroppedBeadData'; 
matrixname = strcat(pwd,foldername,'\UncroppedBeadMatrix',int2str(i),'.mat'); 
uncropped_matrix = load(matrixname);
```

Please do not hesitate to ask any questions that may clarify my question further.

Comment: I would probably try to separate the 3D-ness of the matrix being saved from the memory issue. They may be unrelated. Here is what I tried: "X = randi(10,10,10,10,'uint8')
save X
clear all
load X" and I did get back a 3D matrix (not a struct). Maybe try this out, and also try to save a large 2D matrix, and check if you have the same problem as a large 3D matrix. Also, sharing the dimensions you are dealing with, and your RAM limits may help someone else try to reproduce this.

Comment: @akamath just shared the dimensions of the variable and specs of my computer. I'll try out your before mentioned suggestion in a later on today.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala you should add the line of code where you are calling `save` and where you are calling `load`...

Comment: @Dan I've put up the sections where the calls have been made

Comment: I think it's because you are loading into a variable, i.e. your `load` statement has a LHS assignment. This is what makes it a `struct`, however you can easily get your original matrix by just going `uncropped_matrix.temp_bead`. Another (worse) alternative is to drop the LHS from your load and just call `load(matrixname);`. This should "poof" a variable called `temp_bead` into your workspace rather than the `struct` but it's not good practice. Just extract your matrix out of the `struct`.

Comment: @Dan that is exactly what I was looking for. I guess I did not understand how the `save` and `load` function worked. If you want, I can delete this question.

Comment: No leave it, I'll add this as an answer rather if it does answer the question

Comment: This behavior is clearly stated in the documentation for `load`...

Comment: @excaza that is why I suggested I delete this question. I was just confused about how the variables are separate from the file itself

Comment: @excaza but it's not explained in the docs for `save` so I can see how someone could be confused...

Comment: @Dan, Why would one look for behavior of `load` in the documentation for `save`?

Comment: @excaza it seemed logical to me. One could easily assume that it is `save` that decides on the data-structure and not `load`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are loading into a variable, i.e. your `load` statement has a left hand side assignment. This is what makes it a `struct`. However, you can easily get your original matrix from this `struct`:

```
uncropped_matrix.temp_bead
```

Another (but worse) alternative is to drop the LHS from your `load` and just call

```
load(matrixname);
```

This will "poof" a variable called `temp_bead` into your workspace rather than hassling with the intermediate `struct` but it's not good practice as it makes the code hard to follow since readers can't see where that `temp_bead` variable you are using was created / assigned to.

As Mohsen points out in the comments, the best option is

```
load(matrixname, 'temp_bead');
```

Which will eliminate teh intermediary `struct` and allows readers of the code to see where the data in the variable specified (by the string in) `matrixname` come from.

Comment: An alternative more readable option is `load(matrixname, 'temp_bead');`. Easy to see which variable will be loaded and no extra extraction from struct is required.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia Good suggestion there!